# Is it possible to use Boost.Spirit V2.x without Boost.Fusion?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-fusion

Is it really necessary to wrap structs/classes with Boost.Fusion in order to use them with Boost.Spirit V2.x (especially Boost.Spirit.Qi)? I would much rather use semantic actions to assign to members. If my memory serves me well, this is the way it used to be done in V1.x...

The [calculator example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/spirit/example/qi/calc2_ast.cpp) suggests that it should still be possible. So far, I haven't found a nice way to do it.

I would like to see how you would do it in the [employee example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/spirit/example/qi/employee.cpp). The following doesn't compile, but maybe there is some way to make it work:

```
template <typename Iterator>
struct employee_parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, employee(), ascii::space_type>
{
    employee_parser() : employee_parser::base_type(start)
    {
        using qi::int_;
        using qi::lit;
        using qi::double_;
        using qi::lexeme;
        using ascii::char_;

        quoted_string %= lexeme['"' >> +(char_ - '"') >> '"'];

        start =
            lit("employee")
            >> '{'
            >>  int_[px::bind(&employee::age, qi::_val) = qi::_1] >> ','
            >>  quoted_string[px::bind(&employee::surname, qi::_val) = qi::_1] >> ','
            >>  quoted_string[px::bind(&employee::forename, qi::_val) = qi::_1] >> ','
            >>  double_[px::bind(&employee::salary, qi::_val) = qi::_1]
            >>  '}'
            ;
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), ascii::space_type> quoted_string;
    qi::rule<Iterator, employee(), ascii::space_type> start;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I still had the old fusion printing stuff in there. Funny how mistakes become so much easier to find after you have posted the question... :)

(Since this works, I must have made another error in the production code.)